# How to display the amount of users online?

Tags: php

Im using radipanel to create a staff panel for my website, but my mind has gone blank i have coded this to display the users currently online, but i completely forgot how to display the numbers of users online.

Heres the code i have to display the names of users online;

```
<?php 

                $query = $db->query( "SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM sessions WHERE user_id != '0'" ); 
                    $i = 1; 

                while( $array = $db->assoc( $query ) ) { 

                    $queryU = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '{$array['user_id']}'" ); 
                    $arrayU = $db->assoc( $queryU ); 

                    $queryUG = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM usergroups WHERE id = '{$arrayU['displaygroup']}'" ); 
                    $arrayUG = $db->assoc( $queryUG ); 

                    echo "<a href=\"core.profile?u={$arrayU['username']}\" style=\"color: #{$arrayUG['colour']}; font-weight: bold;\">"; 
                    echo $arrayU['username'];
                                            $coverstatus2 = $arrayU['cover'];
                                            if($coverstatus2 == 1) {
                                            echo " <b style=\"color:#89c35c;\">+</b>";
                                            }elseif($coverstatus2 == 2) {
                                            echo " <b style=\"color:#c24641;\">-</b>";
                                            }elseif($coverstatus2 == 0) {
                                            echo "";
                                            }
                    echo "</a>"; 
                    echo ( $i == $db->num( $query ) ) ? '' : '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'; 

                    $i++; 

                } 

                ?>
```

But how do i display the number?

For example what i want is

Users Online(Number here)
Josh, Tom, Mark

So it would say Users Online (3)

So whats the code to display the number?

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from your code you are getting an array of all current sessions, then using the while statement iterations to echo off each user.  After your i=1; and before your while statement put

```
$array = $db->assoc( $query );
$count = count($array);
```

then you can echo $count where you want it on the page
then

```
while ($array) {
    // Your other code
}
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply, its not working im sure i have done it wrong. http://pastebin.com/qyMHvBbW Thats the code i have so far

Comment: Updated Link, http://pastebin.com/pz6C61Fj

Comment: http://pastebin.com/dzMhGsUg

Comment: Just updated.  How's that?

Comment: Its good apart from the page loads super slow and i get this. http://gyazo.com/efae1f5780b35758c07707690e2eaf8e

Comment: oops.  Still early here.  Try that

Comment: Still doing the same thing :P

Comment: I think I screwed up the link before [http://pastebin.com/zEF8ZEST]

Comment: Wow works amazing, Thanks so much!

Comment: Sorry about before though.  lol  I didn't post the damned updated link  Have a good one  :)

Comment: I think i have :P. I know who to contact when i need help in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Put an int++ counter on the while() statement so with each iteration it calculates the users.  Or to do it without printing the names use a count() method or something similar.

Comment: How would i go about using the count() method?

Comment: I answered it again so I could use the code blocks.  Will that work?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's work for you.
Follow the steps.

1. 1st add a column in user table which store the user last activity in **unix_timestamp** which is you get by using **time()** method in php. So whenever a user do some activity it updates to table for corrosponding user.
   Now you have a column which show user last activity time.

2.Now update last_activity columns with time() method everytime whenever a user do some activity on your server like refreshing page etc.

Now run a query on your time based like for 60 secoonds.

> $query="select * from user_table where last_activity > ( time() - 60 )
>   ;"

This query return you number of online user as well as their data.

Hope Its helpfull to you.

Comment: Tried this but it does not seem to be working?!?

Comment: Why its not working for you.Do you got any error?

Comment: Im unsure on how to add to php my admin. Like how do i add that extra field what do i need to select?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a row called "isonline" to your user's table.

```
$onlineppl=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE isonline='1'");
```

`mysql_num_rows` can help you to count your rows with select.

You when users log off only need to update `isonline='0'` on db.

I hope to help a little.

Comment: Seems to not be working page loads white